# Set featured image to be specific URL, rather than a filename

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a C# programmer - but trying to get into PHP.

I'm using a plugin to import Amazon products into a website.

My host however, blocks me from importing the images - which would normally be used as the featured image.

The code below sets the featured image when trying to import the images.

How can I change it to set the featured image, but to use the full URL to the original Amazon image link (I assume it's $image_url):

```
function set_featured_image( $post_id, $image_url ){
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);

    $filename_ar = explode('.', $filename);
    $filename = sanitize_file_name( $filename_ar[0] ).'.'.$filename_ar[1];
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
        $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else
        $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );

}
```

Or do I manually have to import the image and link to it locally?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to consider hot-linking the image? Keeps it from sapping bandwidth and storage on your site, and avoids the issue of needing to obtain and store a local copy of the image altogether.

Comment: Hi - do you mean linkng directly to the image on Amazon, eg. http://amazon/images/myimage.jpg ?  If so, that's what I'm asking to do - but I'm just not sure how to change the code above, to use the URL of the image, rather than the local filename.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I haven't delved into working with Wordpress plugins myself, but there should already be something around to do this for you I would imagine.

I've just found this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/external-featured-image/ perhaps you could even just look into this code to see how it does it, and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Hi - yeah, that would do the job - but I would still have to manually amend each post.  The Plugin I use imports 50 products at a time - I was hoping to just change the code above to set the featured image to use the full URL $image_url to the image on Amazon.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: Yeah, obviously using the plugin itself would require manual work. Perhaps as I said though, you may be able to see how it is doing what it does (when given a URL by the user, use this in your template as the featured image) and do this automatically in your code, as you said that you assume that the url is given to `$image_url`, so you know the URL; you can use this to set the featured image the same way that the plugin does.